# Duvida Instalação do Laravel e PHP 7.0 WampServer

Tags: php, laravel

Estou com uma duvida.

É a primeira vez que instalo o Laravel e para isso, segui o tutorial do seguinte forum [Tableless](https://tableless.com.br/instalando-laravel-5-2/).

Até ai tudo bem, a instalação está ok, mas ao criar o primeiro projeto, recebo a seguinte mensagem:

[image: prompt de comando]

Alguém sabe como resolver? por que ao olhar o Wamp Server 3.0.8, ele já está setado para o php 7.0, confira na imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: vai na linha de comando e digita `php -v` qual resultado sai ?

Comment: fiz o que vc pediu e apareceu a versão 5.6.25, como eu altero? e sabe me dizer pq o wamp mostra uma versão e o CMD mostra outra?

Comment: Sim Diego, você tem na sua máquina duas versões do `PHP`, uma que o sistema operacional tem como padrão/principal e a outra que é instalado junto com o Wamp, e utilizado pelo apache do Wamp. Tem que mudar nas variáveis de ambiente do Windows. Nesse link explica certinho: https://blog.schoolofnet.com/2015/04/como-instalar-o-php-no-windows-do-jeito-certo-e-usar-o-servidor-embutido/

Comment: Obrigado! problema resolvido! era esse detalhe mesmo, alterei as variáveis de sessão e o problema foi resolvido!

Comment: A pergunta não tem nada haver com HTML5, não use tags que não tem haver com o problema, a sua duvida é sobre configurar o servidor Apache e o PHP.